# Returning value from addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have problem since I'm trying to use reducers and react-redux.
Is there any way to return scroll value ?

```
case constans.SCROLL_POSY:
const test = window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        let supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
        let isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || '') === 'CSS1Compat');
          scroll = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
        return scroll;
        });
return {...state, scrollY: test}
```

Comment: No, or at least, not the way you do it now. Just think about the logic, when would your event listener be triggered?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use addEventListener to get scroll position. Just use the function. 
Create function that returns scrollTop:

```
const getScrollTop = () => {
        let supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
        let isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || '') === 'CSS1Compat');
          scrollTop = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
        return scrollTop;
}
```

Then call it in your reducer:

```
case constans.SCROLL_POSY:
return {...state, scrollY: getScrollTop()};
```